# Time complexity of pseudocode

Tags: time, time-complexity

I have an algorithm that I am trying to find the time complexity for.

```
 (A[1...n]: array of integers) 
    stack S ← empty stack 
    for k ← 1 to n         
        push(S, A[k])        
        x ← 4   
        while (S is not empty) and (x is even)     
             x ← pop(S)
```

I think the while cycle will iterate only once every for iteration which results in O(n). Is this correct?

Comment: Please indent the code properly. It is unclear whether the while loop is inside the for loop or independent.

Comment: It should be  `N*log( N )` where as in your case, i believe it is getting into iterated logarithmic time - `O(log* n)`. Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

This runs in O(n) time. Note that every time we push onto the stack, we immediately pop it off due to assigning `x` to an even value; you are correct that it only iterates once. The while loop is completely unnecessary, and we are left with

```
 (A[1...n]: array of integers) 
    stack S ← empty stack 
    for k ← 1 to n         
        push(S, A[k])
        pop(S)
```

which is clearly O(n).